# Implementing Vercel KV with LangChain (Vercel AI SDK)

Tags: typescript, next.js, langchain, vercel-ai

This is the code for the route.ts file in the example repo that uses the Vercel KV:

```js
import { kv } from '@vercel/kv'
import { OpenAIStream, StreamingTextResponse } from 'ai'
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai-edge'

import { auth } from '@/auth'
import { nanoid } from '@/lib/utils'

export const runtime = 'edge'

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY
})

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration)

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const json = await req.json()
  const { messages, previewToken } = json
  const userId = (await auth())?.user.id

  if (!userId) {
    return new Response('Unauthorized', {
      status: 401
    })
  }

  if (previewToken) {
    configuration.apiKey = previewToken
  }

  const res = await openai.createChatCompletion({
    model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
    messages,
    temperature: 0.7,
    stream: true
  })

  const stream = OpenAIStream(res, {
    async onCompletion(completion) {
      const title = json.messages[0].content.substring(0, 100)
      const id = json.id ?? nanoid()
      const createdAt = Date.now()
      const path = `/chat/${id}`
      const payload = {
        id,
        title,
        userId,
        createdAt,
        path,
        messages: [
          ...messages,
          {
            content: completion,
            role: 'assistant'
          }
        ]
      }
      await kv.hmset(`chat:${id}`, payload)
      await kv.zadd(`user:chat:${userId}`, {
        score: createdAt,
        member: `chat:${id}`
      })
    }
  })

  return new StreamingTextResponse(stream)
}
```

And here is the code in the Vercel AI SDK for using LangChain.

```
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { Message as VercelChatMessage, StreamingTextResponse } from 'ai';
 
import { ChatOpenAI } from 'langchain/chat_models/openai';
import { BytesOutputParser } from 'langchain/schema/output_parser';
import { PromptTemplate } from 'langchain/prompts';
 
export const runtime = 'edge';
 
/**
 * Basic memory formatter that stringifies and passes
 * message history directly into the model.
 */
const formatMessage = (message: VercelChatMessage) => {
  return `${message.role}: ${message.content}`;
};
 
const TEMPLATE = `You are a pirate named Patchy. All responses must be extremely verbose and in pirate dialect.
 
Current conversation:
{chat_history}
 
User: {input}
AI:`;
 
/*
 * This handler initializes and calls a simple chain with a prompt,
 * chat model, and output parser. See the docs for more information:
 *
 * https://js.langchain.com/docs/guides/expression_language/cookbook#prompttemplate--llm--outputparser
 */
export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  const body = await req.json();
  const messages = body.messages ?? [];
  const formattedPreviousMessages = messages.slice(0, -1).map(formatMessage);
  const currentMessageContent = messages[messages.length - 1].content;
 
  const prompt = PromptTemplate.fromTemplate(TEMPLATE);
  /**
   * See a full list of supported models at:
   * https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/models/
   */
  const model = new ChatOpenAI({
    temperature: 0.8,
  });
 
  /**
   * Chat models stream message chunks rather than bytes, so this
   * output parser handles serialization and encoding.
   */
  const outputParser = new BytesOutputParser();
 
  /*
   * Can also initialize as:
   *
   * import { RunnableSequence } from "langchain/schema/runnable";
   * const chain = RunnableSequence.from([prompt, model, outputParser]);
   */
  const chain = prompt.pipe(model).pipe(outputParser);
 
  const stream = await chain.stream({
    chat_history: formattedPreviousMessages.join('\n'),
    input: currentMessageContent,
  });
 
  return new StreamingTextResponse(stream);
}
```

Any idea on how to implement the KV with LangChain?
Your help will be greatly appreciated.

I am struggling to find a solution to implementing the Vercel KV with LangChain.